# Avoiding lateinit

Tags: kotlin, lateinit

I've got a class that has a structure similar to this:

```kotlin
class A {
    lateinit var x: String
    lateinit var y: String
    lateinit var z: String

    init {
        reset()
    }

    fun reset() {
        val temp = some complex calculation...
        x = temp.let {
            some other complex calculation...
        }
        y = temp.let {
            some other complex calculation...
        }
        z = temp.let {
            some other complex calculation...
        }
    }
}
```

If the body of `reset` was in `init`, I wouldn't need to declare the variables `lateinit`. But because I'm calling `reset()` in `init`, and I don't refer to the variables directly, the compiler doesn't see that the variables are definitely initialized, and therefore they have to be declared `lateinit`.

Is it possible to somehow tell the compiler that the variables are in fact initialized?

I've tried declaring `reset` as inline but it still wouldn't compile without `lateinit`.

Comment: What is this complex initialization? Maybe a factory function would do the trick better?

Comment: A factory function would work, but the point is that `temp` is only required during the initialization/resetting of multiple properties, so I didn't want to hold on to anything after that (e.g. by making it a private property).

Comment: Calling non-static functions in constructor is generally considered bad practice and is very likely to lead to bugs because you're operating on a non-initialized (or partially initialized) object. Having a factory or usecase that prepares xyz you can simply assign to your fields seems like better solution you can put in your init block.

Comment: I would put `private set` after each property and call it good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77523646/avoiding-lateinit#comment136670988_77523789) that it is a priority for you to avoid recalculation *or* object-lifetime storing of the dependency which initializes your properties. To achieve that, you can let the primary constructor accept a simple argument that's not a property of the class (this is an adaptation to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77523789/10553893) solution):

```kotlin
class A(dependency: Dependency) {
     private val x = dependency.getX()
     private val y = dependency.getY()
     private val z = dependency.getZ()

}
```

note how the `private val` is no longer present for the `dependency` constructor argument. Now, judging from your code snippet, the value of `dependency` (or `temp` in your snippet) is not supposed to be a parameter but rather to be calculated once the class is instantiated. To achieve this, you can use a secondary constructor *or* a companion object factory function that calls the primary and injects the dependency that was just calculated. If you want to prohibit injecting the dependency from the outside, you can additionally make your primary constructor private:

```kotlin
class A private constructor(dependency: Dependency) {
    private val x = dependency.getX()
    private val y = dependency.getY()
    private val z = dependency.getZ()
    
    constructor() : this(aFunctionThatCalculatesDependency()) {}
```

again, if the logic for calculating `dependency` cannot be represented by a single expression that you can pass to `this()`, use a `companion object` factory function instead. If you really want something that still *looks* like a constructor, though, there's also the pseudoconstructor pattern (`invoke()` operator function on the companion object)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's achievable and it should be intended *by design* as you can call `reset` in another moment during your app development, leading you into a crash (or you might forget adding it to the constructor.)

What you can do, if you are sure that your variables get evaluated on `init` block only, you can just do it in the declaration part:

```kotlin
private val x = dependency.getX()
private val y = dependency.getY()
private val z = dependency.getZ()
```

So your class would look something like this, you don't even need an `init` block.

```kotlin
class A(private val dependency: Dependency) {
     private val x = dependency.getX() //or it could be var
     private val y = dependency.getY()
     private val z = dependency.getZ()

}
```

And if you still need the `reset` function, then just declare the variables as `var` and "reset" them on `reset`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I was hoping to avoid injecting the dependency, as the calculation that is assigned to a temporary variable in my `reset` function is just calling a set of static functions, and I didn't want to hold on to a value longer than necessary (the temp variable is only required for setting x, y and z.)